# jQuery Waypoint - Want to reverse function

Tags: jquery, jquery-waypoints

I am using jQuery Waypoint to invoke a "Back to Top" button when you reach the `div.main-content` area of my site like so:

```
$('div.page.event div.main-content').waypoint(function() {
    $('button.scrollToTop').fadeIn(200);
});
```

But I can't figure out how to reverse it so that when you get back up to `header.main-header` the button goes away. I've tried this:

```
$('div.page.event header.main-header').waypoint(function() {
    $('button.scrollToTop').fadeOut(200);
});
```

But that doesn't work. I'm sure this is overly simple and I'm just missing the point. Can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `direction` parameter that is passed to the waypoint function. Its value will be "down" or "up" depending on which direction the user is scrolling when they cross the waypoint:

```
$('div.page.event div.main-content').waypoint(function(direction) {
  if (direction === 'down') {
    $('button.scrollToTop').fadeIn(200);
  }
  else {
    $('button.scrollToTop').fadeOut(200);
  }
});
```